# Matrix Multi Upload JS Issue

Tags: matrix, file-uploads

So I've looked at this post:

[When trying to update indexes a get a JS error and it never finished](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13002/when-trying-to-update-indexes-a-get-a-js-error-and-it-never-finished)

I added `$config['assets_site_url'] = '/index.php';` to my config file but I'm still getting this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < matrix_multi_upload.js:166`:

[image]

Does anyone have any other ideas on what could be causing this issue?

Matrix allows me to upload photos, but I REALLY like MMU!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am having the same error - Was this ever resolved????

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I asked the question a week ago and received no responses... desperation has set in.

Comment: I understand. Using the comments on the question is the best place to ask questions about a question, rather than posting as an answer. There is now an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

That setting is "mmu_site_url" instead of "assets_site_url", for Matrix Multi Upload accessory :)

[Source](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/matrix_multi_upload/blob/master/ee2/third_party/matrix_multi_upload/acc.matrix_multi_upload.php#L118)

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. What gives? :) Setting `$config['mmu_site_url']   = '/index.php';` doesn't do anything for me in my config.php file :/// It looks like it's referencing this `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < matrix_multi_upload.js:166` I even updated that file from MMU's GitHub page to no avail.

Comment: I have confirmed that the photos are uploading, but the rows are not being created in the matrix field.

Comment: Shoot over CP access to support@pixelandtonic.com - have to take a closer look :)

Comment: Hi Andris, email has been sent!

Answer (score 0):

The console log message `SyntaxError: Unexpected token "<"` may be caused by a missing javascript file, intercepted by some 404 or HTACCESS rule. So, ...

- Is the `themes` folder for Matrix MultiUpload there, in `/themes/third_party/matrix_multi_upload`?
- Is it accessible over HTTP?